# Multidimensional array json_encoded

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I try to return a multidimensional array of dates and revenues each date as JSon array in order to display a chart in my panel dashboard. Unfortunately the chart makes some problem, when I don't hardcode my JSon Array, thus I am debugging it right now and I wonder why my json_encoded array looks so strange.

This is my Panel, which draws the chart and requests the data from data.php:

```
jQuery.getJSON("data.php", { request: "revenues" }, function (result) {
    var revenues = result["amount"];
    alert(revenues);
    $(".monthly-sales").sparkline(revenues, {
        type: 'bar',
        barColor: '#ff4e50',
        height: '55px',
        width: '100%',
        barWidth: 8,
        barSpacing: 1
    });
});
```

The data.php:

```
elseif($request == "revenues"){
    // Output Revenues per day from nexus store
    $revenues = array();
    $revenues["dates"] = array();
    $revenues["amount"] = array();
    $sql = "select i_total as revenue, date(FROM_UNIXTIME(i_date)) as date FROM nexus_invoices WHERE i_status='paid' GROUP BY date(FROM_UNIXTIME(i_date)) ORDER BY i_date DESC LIMIT 0,10";
    $rows = $db->query($sql);
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $revenues["dates"][] = $row['date'];
        $revenues["amount"][] = floatval($row['revenue']);
    }
    //$revenues["amount"] = [1,5,5.5,5.4,5.8,6,8,9,13,12,10,11.5,9,8,5,8,9];
    echo json_encode($revenues);
}
```

The JSon result of this code is how I expect it:

```
{
    "dates":[
        "2015-06-13","2015-06-12","2015-06-10","2015-06-09","2015-06-07",
        "2015-06-06","2015-06-05","2015-06-04","2015-06-02","2015-05-31"
    ],
    "amount":[8,22,8,8,22,8,8,8,8,8]
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work for an unknown reason. To debug this further I have uncommented the line which hardcodes the `$revenues["amount"]` and commented the second line of the foreach. Then it worked fine. The result of this json_encoded echo is this:

```
{
    "dates":[
        "2015-06-13","2015-06-12","2015-06-10","2015-06-09","2015-06-07",
        "2015-06-06","2015-06-05","2015-06-04","2015-06-02","2015-05-31"
    ],
    "amount":[1,5,5.5,5.4,5.8,6,8,9,13,12,10,11.5,9,8,5,8,9]
}
```

How it looks like when I hardcode the array: [image]

How it looks like when I fill the array from my database: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is not in the json array rather the sparkline plugin.

try adding this when you display the DB data: `chartRangeMin:5`

```
$(".monthly-sales").sparkline(revenues, {
        type: 'bar',
        barColor: '#ff4e50',
        height: '55px',
        width: '100%',
        barWidth: 8,
        barSpacing: 1,
       chartRangeMin:5 
    });
```

Comment: As you can see in my posted JSON result of the database query this is not the case. I limited my DB query to 0,10 and thus I get my mentioned JSOn array with 10 values. Let me quote it again `[8,22,8,8,22,8,8,8,8,8]`

Comment: i understand, but you are getting only 2 bars as it groups it - the spakline i mean as you have only 2 values

Comment: i played a bit with sparkline, can you upload a fiddle or share the graph of the db results?

Comment: Chartrangemin solves the issue, what is this property good for ??

Comment: As your problem wasnt that it didnt display all 10 bars but that the bars with value of 8 were almost flat to the bottom as the bars with the 22 value were top - so it looked like there are not there. in order to boost them a bit so the value 8 won't be that small, we use the chartRangeMin that sets the min value for the Y-axis. you can read more here: http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-docs